# How to run SQL queries on tables defined on streaming data asynchronously in Spark Streaming?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

The official Spark Streaming Programming Guide in [DataFrame and SQL Operations](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#dataframe-and-sql-operations) section mentions about running SQL queries asynchronously:

> You can also run SQL queries on tables defined on streaming data from a different thread (that is, asynchronous to the running StreamingContext).

Are there any examples/samples that shows how to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's really interesting that the docs had to mention it since it is a fact that any temporary table is accessible for any thread using the same `SparkSession`.

I would go about this as follows:

```
// Create a fixed thread pool to execute asynchronous tasks
val executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1)
dstream.foreachRDD { rdd =>
  import org.apache.spark.sql._
  val spark = SparkSession.builder.config(rdd.sparkContext.getConf).getOrCreate
  import spark.implicits._
  import spark.sql

  val records = rdd.toDF("record")
  records.createOrReplaceTempView("records")

  // Submit a asynchronous task to execute a SQL query
  executorService.submit {
    new Runnable {
      override def run(): Unit = {
        sql("select * from records").show(truncate = false)
      }
    }
  }
}
```